# What is going on with __vector_base_common?

Tags: c++, libc++

I wanted to see at how C++ vector is made. I found this,
Implementation is LLVM compiler https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/src/vector.cpp appleclang

src/vector.cpp:

```
#include "vector"

_LIBCPP_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_STD

template class _LIBCPP_CLASS_TEMPLATE_INSTANTIATION_VIS __vector_base_common<true>;

_LIBCPP_END_NAMESPACE_STD
```

Implementation https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/vector appleclang LLVM.

include/vector:

```
// .. deleted code

template <bool>
class __vector_base_common
{
protected:
    _LIBCPP_ALWAYS_INLINE __vector_base_common() {}
    _LIBCPP_NORETURN void __throw_length_error() const;
    _LIBCPP_NORETURN void __throw_out_of_range() const;
};

template <bool __b>
void
__vector_base_common<__b>::__throw_length_error() const
{
    _VSTD::__throw_length_error("vector");
}

template <bool __b>
void
__vector_base_common<__b>::__throw_out_of_range() const
{
    _VSTD::__throw_out_of_range("vector");
}

_LIBCPP_EXTERN_TEMPLATE(class _LIBCPP_EXTERN_TEMPLATE_TYPE_VIS __vector_base_common<true>)

// .. deleted code

template <class _Tp, class _Allocator>
class __vector_base
    : protected __vector_base_common<true>

// .. deleted code

class _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS vector
    : private __vector_base<_Tp, _Allocator>

// .. deleted code
```

I have many questions how a vector is made.. it feel embarrassing to ask even one.. but.. why is __vector_base_common taking bool template parameter? It doesn't seem to use it, and I verified only use in code is `__vector_base_common<true>`, the `false` value is not used.

*Edit:* There have been multiple suggestion relating `vector<bool>` to this. Only one specialisation of the above bool parameter is used (`true`). This is what vector special looks like

```
template <class _Allocator>
class _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS vector<bool, _Allocator>
    : private __vector_base_common<true>
```

The difference looks between private versus protected... Is this a space optimisation for vector not needing those throwing member functions? Still I have question why `__vector_base_common` needs a template parameter. Is this C++ pattern with a name?

Comment: This is an implementation detail and only relevant to the specific implementation you are studying. It would be helpful to know which one you are looking at.

Comment: Stroustrup explains a lot of details in [Appendix E](http://www.stroustrup.com/3rd_safe.pdf) ("Standard-Library Exception Safety") of *The C++ Programming Language* (at least the inheritance part, which is pretty clever).

Comment: Perhaps the template argument is used because either `__vector_base_common<true>` or `__vector_base_common<false>` is explicitly specialized. It may have something to do with `std::vector<bool>` being a special case, where it would inherit from one `__vector_base_common` where as the general case would inherit from the other.

Comment: Implementation is LLVM compiler https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/src/vector.cpp  appleclang?

Comment: @molbdnilo --- are you refering to vector : __vector_base inheritance technique described in Appendix E?, in fact i am confused about __vector_base : _vector_base_common<true>

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux in fact, implementation technique only uses __vector_base_common<true> it does not use false to change it appears to me.

Comment: @HenryF1 `__vector_base` is a new type that derives from `__vector_base_common<true>` which is `__vector_base_common` with `true` is given as it's template argument.

Comment: @HenryF1 It's possible another type in another file uses the `false` variance.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux there are no occurrences of vector_base_common<false> in whole project

Comment: @HenryF1 Are you sure? The `false` portion may be evaluated at compile time or be provided by another template argument. For example `template<bool B> class something : public __vector_base_common<B> {}`. I suspect it might look something like `template<class T> __bool_vector : protected __vector_base_common<std::is_same<T, bool>::value>`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux These are all occurrences in libcxx svn repo

```src/vector.cpp:14:template class _LIBCPP_CLASS_TEMPLATE_INSTANTIATION_VIS __vector_base_common<true>;
include/vector:301:__vector_base_common<__b>::__throw_length_error() const
include/vector:308:__vector_base_common<__b>::__throw_out_of_range() const
include/vector:313:_LIBCPP_EXTERN_TEMPLATE(class _LIBCPP_EXTERN_TEMPLATE_TYPE_VIS __vector_base_common<true>)
include/vector:317:    : protected __vector_base_common<true>
include/vector:2149:    : private __vector_base_common<true>``` (they are all <true> eventually)

Comment: How `vector<bool>` is so radically different from `vector<anythingelse>` was one of the great design controversies that will live on forever.  The cppreference.com site had to dedicate a [separate page to it](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool), the library you looked at did as well.

Comment: So I found one difference with `vector<bool>`, it inherits `vector_base_common` using protected, whereas `vector_base` inherits using private. I need to read about that, but still my question remains about the template parameter. I updated the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is an implementation trick so that the library can be either used only as headers, or have a precompiled part.

Some of `vector`'s member functions do not depend on the template arguments at all; specifically, the helper functions that throw exceptions. It is therefore possible (unlike the parts that depend on the template parameters) to compile them once and put them in a shared library. This is what happens on MacOS, for example.

On the other hand, on platforms where the library is not distributed with the OS, it is more convenient for the user if he doesn't have to distribute the shared library, but can instead use the library as header-only, i.e. include `<vector>` and be done with it, without having to add flags to the linker invocation in the build.

This means that you need the code for these functions to be available in the headers, but if you use the shared library variant, it should not actually get compiled when using the header.

The trick presented here is a way to achieve that. First, the implementation is put into a template, so that it may live in the header without generating multiple definition errors. The template in question only has a dummy parameter; the important thing is that it is a template, not that it has any particular parameters. This is a common technique used by header-only libraries.

Now you can use the library header-only. But if you want to use the shared library variant, you actually need to compile the code ahead of time and suppress code generation for the library user. Explicit template instantiation can be used for that.

So you put an extern template declaration in the header:

```
extern template class _LIBCPP_EXTERN_TEMPLATE_TYPE_VIS __vector_base_common<true>;
```

So the header now contains an explicit specialization declaration, suppressing code generation for the template members.

And then you take a source file, put in the explicit instantiation, and compile it to a shared library.

```
template class _LIBCPP_CLASS_TEMPLATE_INSTANTIATION_VIS __vector_base_common<true>;
```

Now you have the shared library usage covered, but you destroyed the ability to use the library header-only. To get that back, you need to make the `extern template` declaration optional, depending on the usage mode of the library. So you wrap the declaration in a macro whose definition depends on the mode:

```
_LIBCPP_EXTERN_TEMPLATE(class _LIBCPP_EXTERN_TEMPLATE_TYPE_VIS __vector_base_common<true>)
```

This macro is [conditionally defined](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/efb6d58bf987fc9a35c06e4159c53630182a20d7/include/__config#L914):

```
#ifdef _LIBCPP_DISABLE_EXTERN_TEMPLATE
#define _LIBCPP_EXTERN_TEMPLATE(...)
#endif

#ifndef _LIBCPP_EXTERN_TEMPLATE
#define _LIBCPP_EXTERN_TEMPLATE(...) extern template __VA_ARGS__;
#endif
```

So if you're in header-only mode (`_LIBCPP_DISABLE_EXTERN_TEMPLATE` is defined), the declaration vanishes. If you're in shared library mode, the declaration is there, preventing code generation.

---

The reason `vector<bool>` derives privately from `__vector_base_common` is because it doesn't have any derived classes itself that need access to the throw helpers. `vector<T>` derives from `__vector_base<T>`, and `__vector_base<T>` in turn derives from `__vector_base_common`; so for `vector<T>` to have access to the `__vector_base_common` members, `__vector_base<T>` must derive from `__vector_base_common` as `protected`.